# Is there an IDE for D with integrated debugger?

Tags: ide, debugging, d

Is there an IDE for D with integrated debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Descent](http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent) has the ability to use a debugger. Not exactly what you asked but...

Comment: Looks like Descent is almost exactly what he asked for. :)

Answer (score 3):

The **DDBG** *Win32 Debugger* works with a few IDEs - http://ddbg.mainia.de/

Answer (score 2):

[Poseidon](http://dsource.org/projects/poseidon).

Comment: Poseidon doesn't look like it's being actively developed anymore.  In fact, it doesn't seem to have made a new release since I tried it nearly a year ago.  At that time, I couldn't get it correctly set up.  Perhaps that's because it's still in alpha or pre-alpha (ver .221).

Comment: @Kevin, I do think the development has slowed to a stop, Frank supposedly got it working with the new DWT, but can't get commit rights.